# Highcharts tooltip displayed over div

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, tooltip

I'd like to have the pie chart tooltips to be displayed over the div partially hiding the chart.

Here is my HTML structure. The `.circle-text` element contains my div and the `.container` the chart.

```
<div class="bubble">
    <div class="circle-text"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried solutions using CSS :

```
.highcharts-container {
    position: inherit !important;
}
.highcharts-tooltip {
    z-index: 9998 !important;
}
.highcharts-tooltip span {
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid green;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:9999!important;
}
```

or Highcharts properties :

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>',
    style: {
        'color': 'pink',
        'z-index': '9999'
    }
}
```

But none of them has worked so far.

My div covering the chart has the following style and I don't see how it might interfere with the tooltip z-index.

```
.circle-text {
    position: absolute;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #3A3A4F;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
}
```

https://codepen.io/SamHCadman/pen/MzzrGJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your styles respected in relation to other html elements, set `useHTML` property for tooltip to `true`:

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    padding: 0,
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>',
    style: {
        'color': 'pink',
        'z-index': '9999'
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4r9Lkcz7/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.useHTML

Answer (score 0):

Sam, I tried playing with your JS as well as your CSS and was not able to get the tooltip above the `.circle-text`. However, I did add this animation in as a workaround. Please feel free to ignore this if you are firm on achieving the result you described.

The only changes I made were to your CSS (`.circle-text`). This will cause the `.circle-text` to disappear when `.bubble` is hovered over.

```
/* https://anacidre.com/creating-circle-text-using-html-css/ */
.circle-text {
    position: absolute;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #3A3A4F;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
    transition: transform 500ms;
}

.bubble:hover .circle-text {
    transform: scale(0);
}
```